# Given Netezza does not support First and Last when aggregating, how to proceed?

Tags: sql, netezza

I would like to group data on some column called CustID and select their first or the last mortgage even if the mortgages were originated on the same date. How do you do that in Netezza? In MS Access I normally use the First or Last aggregation functions for that.

Data comes like this:

```
CustID  mortgageID  pass_dt

101      090234W    1-23-1989

101      103120X    5-20-2020

101      103121V    5-20-2020
```

So here I want either the second or the third record but not both when as extra criterium pass_dt = 5-20-2020.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the entire record, use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by custid order by pass_dt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this made me learn a few new things! Works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustID, max(mortgageID), max(pass_dt) from t1 group by 1;
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: This actually also worked just because the SQL server could still select only 1 item from the mortgageID list via the MAX function. Thanks.